# Bakery workers washing Negel Vasser

Tags: food, cooking-bishul, netilat-yadayim-washing, heterodox, employment

In my local bakery there are Jewish non religious workers. Is there a concern that perhaps when they are handling the baked goods they have not washed negel Vasser (morning n'tilas yadayim)?

Comment: http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/376  Question #3: Must a caterer insist that his non-Jewish employees wash negel vasser before beginning work?

Answer: One need not insist that the non-Jewish employees wash negel vasser since their touching food does not create any ruach ra.

Comment: However I guess the question remains with Jewish non religous workers.

Comment: There probably is such a concern, because if they aren't religious, I wouldn't expect them to be careful to wash their hands in the morning.

Comment: There is no mention of this netilah in the gemara or idea of tumah, it's a later "chiddush". So why be concerned?

Comment: I heard R' Ovadya does a somewhat involved calculation, with the result that by the time they get to work they've probably washed their hands 3 times already (bathroom, breakfast, brushing teeth or something).  He says that's good enough.  ק"ו at a bakery where they'll wash their hands another time before starting work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Revach](http://revach.net/article.php?id=3861&style=print) Rabbi Moshe Sternbuch Shlita says that if they are Mechalel Shabbos B'Farhesia they have the same Halacha as a non Jew and there is no requirement for them to wash their hands. However he concludes that if the owner has control then he should require that they wash their hands three times prior to handling the food.

Comment: For the thing about if they're considered non-Jews, he concludes ומיהו ד"ז חידוש וצ"ע טובא, which implies that he is in doubt lehalachah (but he does end up permitting it bedi'avad for different reasons): http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=6